# Bootstrap element to bottom with flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a snippet with my code of section height `height: 450px;`. Please see snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .get-tour .form-block {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .get-tour .form-block label {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<section style="min-height: 450px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        Use the .flex-fill class on a series of sibling elements to force them into widths .... align-items , flex-direction: column , and margin-top: auto
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        Use the .flex-fill class on a series of sibling elements to force them into widths .... align-items , flex-direction: column , and margin-top: auto
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">

      <div class="get-tour d-flex align-items-end">
        <form action="">
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>When</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Date </label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Qty ночей</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Who</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Type</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How I can put to bottom my form `get-tour` with flexbox? I tried add class `d-flex align-items-end` but my code is not work. Why? If I set `height: 100%` to container or on my section also not work. Please help fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: do u want to have the form at the bottom I'm right ?

Comment: Do you want to put `get-tour` to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @AmareshSM yes, form at the bottom. You're right

Comment: @user9408899 yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I set height: 100% to container or on my section also not work.

You need to set `body` and `html`'s height to 100% as well. Because they wrap all of your content.

Then, you can use `flexbox` layout model to put your `get-tour` at the bottom of your page.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
}

section .container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .get-tour .form-block {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .get-tour .form-block label {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<section style="min-height: 450px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        Use the .flex-fill class on a series of sibling elements to force them into widths .... align-items , flex-direction: column , and margin-top: auto
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        Use the .flex-fill class on a series of sibling elements to force them into widths .... align-items , flex-direction: column , and margin-top: auto
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">

      <div class="get-tour ">
        <form action="">
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>When</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Date </label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Qty ночей</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Who</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>Type</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```